# Can I use "(" in preprocessor concatenation in C?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

The following gives this error in GCC: *pasting "func_x" and "(" does not give a valid preprocessing token*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LOG_FUNC(fname) printf( #fname " %d\n", fname ## ())

int func_x(){
  return 0;
}

int main(){
  LOG_FUNC(func_x);
  return 0;
}
```

However, when I hover the mouse on top of the function, it shows that the macro expands to following expression that works without a problem

```
printf("func_x" " %d\n", func_x())
```

Is it because the parenthesis is not allowed in pre processor string concatenation?

Comment: Why exactly are you putting `##` there? You are not concatenating two string, and you don't want the result to be a string.

Comment: `##` is for token concatenation — the result must be an identifier.  You can simply remove the `##` from the macro.  See [§6.10.3.3 The `##` operator](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.3.3) for details, including the sentence: _If the result is not a valid preprocessing token, the behavior is undefined._  The result of the `##` operator must be a valid pp-token, and a name followed by parentheses is not a valid pp-token (it contains several pp-tokens).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: As the rest of your comment after the first sentence indicates, the result does not need to be an identifier, just a preprocessor token.

Comment: @EricPostpischil — yes, but for most practical purposes, that means an identifier.  The number of times you combine `>` and `=` with `##` to create `>=` (or similar) is strictly limited.  The OP is already having problems; there's no need to over-complicate the commentary with super-accurate but inscrutable information like that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: But you have complicated it, by using “identifier” inaccurately in one place and “processor token” correctly in others. And, sure, `>=` is hardly ever created, but appending type suffixes is a usage I have seen (as in the `stdint.h` macros to create constants of particular types).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get your code to compile, change `LOG_FUNC` to:

```c
#define LOG_FUNC(fname) printf( #fname " %d\n", fname())
```

If you want to concatenate two strings together, just write them next to each other, separated by whitespace.  It is OK if they contain parens.  You don't have to use the preprocessor for this, but you can:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define MY_STR(f) f "(\n"

int main() {
  puts(MY_STR("hi")); // outputs "hi("
  return 0;
}
```